# PHP Table overflow

Tags: php, html, css

I am building a system where you track your assignments.
I have now come to a problem that the DIV I wish to place this table in causes an overflow..... Okay, not a problem- except it doesn't overflow horizonitly  ...please can someone help me

Please can someone help me get this to fit in .... or help me put this table in a table to fit in a 1100 x 545 px area..

I've got the spacing to something good looking... put it's making the overflow horizontal

```
$UArr = array("u1" => "Introduction to Marketing ", 
             "u2" => "Maintenance Unit ", 
             "u3" => "Starting a biz", 
            "u4" => "Web Design", 
            "u5" => "Webserver / PHP", 
            "u6" => "Modeling / Multimedia Design" ,
             "u7" => "CISCO 1 " , 
             "u8" => "CISCO 2 " , 
             "u9" => "C&G Marketing"); ///unit array

$AArr = array("a1" => "Assignment 1", "a2" => "Assignment 2", "a3" => "Assignment 3", "a4" => "Assignment 4"); //assigment array
$TArr = array("t1" => "Task 1", "t2" => "Task 2", "t3" => "Task 3", "t4" => "Task 4"); //task array

$Connection = mysql_connect($host,$username, $password);
mysql_select_db("dbname");

$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tracker` WHERE `CollegeID`='collegeid' ");
if(mysql_num_rows($Result) == 1) {
    while($Data = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
        $i = 0;
        $Assignment = "";
        $Unit = "";
        $Task = "";
        echo "<table style=\"float:left;\" width=\"200\" border=\"0\" overflow:scroll;>";
        foreach($Data as $Item => $Value) {
            if(!is_numeric($Item) && $Item !== "CollegeID") {
                if($i == 0) {
                    $Unit = substr($Item, 0, 2);
                    $Assignment = substr($Item, 2, 2);
                    $Task = substr($Item, 4, 2);
                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$UArr[$Unit]."</p></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$AArr[substr($Item, 2, 2)]."</p></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td width=\"10\">".$TArr[$Task]."</td><td width=\"10\">".DropDown($Item, $Value)."</td></tr>";
                }
                if($Unit !== substr($Item, 0, 2)) {
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<table style=\"float:left;\" width=\"200\" border=\"0\">";
                    $Unit = substr($Item, 0, 2);
                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$UArr[substr($Item, 0, 2)]."</p></td></tr>";
                }
                if($Assignment !== substr($Item, 2, 2)) {
                    $Assignment = substr($Item, 2, 2);
                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$AArr[substr($Item, 2, 2)]."</p></td></tr>";
                }
                if($Task !== substr($Item, 4, 2)) {
                    $Task = substr($Item, 4, 2);
                    echo "<tr><td width=\"10\">".$TArr[$Task]."</td><td width=\"50\">".DropDown($Item, $Value)."</td></tr>";
                }
                $i++;
            }

        }
        echo "</table>";
```

[image: this is kinda how it looks, except the spacing is better and 4 units are overflowing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Not an big issue with the scrolling. what i suggest to you that take a div and put a desired height width you want and apply the css as

.divName 
{
height: //specify
widht: //specify
overflow:scroll;  
overflow-x:scroll; 
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

and put the result in this div

Comment: I've included it in the DIV's CSS, and for sizing I increased the widths of the table and used a lot of `<br / >` on the unit headings.. looks okay now

Comment: Thanx Rsmithy for accepting code, it will appreciated me to work more in future.

Answer (score 0):

To make it overflow horizontally, just put it in another `<div>` with exact value of width (width of one table * how many tables you have).

In this example use 9 tables*200px = 1800px

I also recommend using width of table in style or css class like:

```
<table style="float:left;width:200px;border-width:0;overflow:scroll;">
```

Your code is messy, needs to be rearranged

Comment: currently I've substituted with `<br /> <br />` on the unit name array... I'll see what this is like in other browsers and resolutions... but I'm going to call it a night... I'm starting to go code blind... thanks for your help